# Mockito Spy doReturn calls original method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I am new to Mockito. I am aware that spy object will never call original method for `doReturn`, But in my code, which is not happening

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

class MyClass {
    public int method1(){
        int x =10;
        x = method2(2);
        return x;
    }

    public int method2(int y){
        method3();
        return 20;
    }

    public int method3(){
       return 30;
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Method1Test {
    private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    @Before
    public void setup(){}

    @Test
    public void test01(){
        MyClass spyMyClass = spy(myClass);
        doReturn(28).when(spyMyClass).method2(any());
        int a = spyMyClass.method1();
        assertTrue("We did it!!!",a==20);
    }
}
```

Below is the **error stacktrace:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.Method1Test.test01(Method1Test.java:45)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>         at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>         at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>         at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
>         at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
>
> ```
> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
> Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
>
> -> at com.Method1Test.test01(Method1Test.java:45)
> ```

Please someone help me out on above and also provide me fix for above issue.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you paste the whole Junit test class (including imports) ?

Comment: What is it you intend to happen? I see that you are stubbing it to return 28 but asserting it will return 20. Which is it you expect?

Comment: @GuillaumeS I've added imports , pls check above

Comment: @Dean Can you pls tell why iam getting NPE above in stacktrace, any idea? and why does doReturn above calling original method for spy object above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by a type mismatch on the parameter being passed to `method2`. That's what this part of the exception message is telling you:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

The following test passes:

```
@Test
public void test01(){
    MyClass spyMyClass = spy(myClass);
    doReturn(28).when(spyMyClass).method2(anyInt());
    int a = spyMyClass.method1();
    assertTrue("We did it!!!",a==28);
}
```

There are two changes here:

1. Use `anyInt()` instead of `any()`
2. Assert that `a==28` because you are telling the stub to return `28`

Comment: Given that the message reads "We did it!!", he may have wanted it to fail.

Comment: I have one doubt: Assume, my method is having like this public int method2(Foo foo), then can I pass as : doReturn(28).when(spyMyClass).method2(fooMockObj); ??

Comment: If you read the complete exception message you'll see that the authors of Mockito have anticipated exactly this situation: "This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use"

Comment: So, the issue you encountered is a result of using a non specific object matcher - `any()` - for a primitive parameter. This will not apply if your parameter is changed from a primitive to, say, a `Foo`.